# Gehalt «stunden»

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Ein Bekannter (aus Deutschland) hat erzählt, dass er einem Mitarbeiter das Gehalt um zwei Monate «stunden» müsse, also dem Mitarbeiter das Gehalt erst zwei Monate später auszahlen kann. In der Schweiz ist mir dieser Wortgebrauch bisher nicht geläufig. Wo wird diese Formulierung so verwendet?

Comment: http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&lemma=stunden 

Vielleicht findet man hier was brauchbares :)

Comment: An sich ist die Verwendung "so rum" auch ganz einfach falsch: Es ist der Gläubiger (bei Gehalt wohl der Mitarbeiter), der dem Schuldner (hier wohl der Arbeitgeber) einen Betrag *stundet*, und damit ein vereinbartes Zahlungsziel verstreichen lässt.

Comment: In der Tat, das Wort *stunden* (und zwar eine Schuld) ist völlig wörterbuchkonformes Deutsch. In der in der Frage zitierten Verwendung *das Gehalt stunden* würde ich allerdings auf erstes auf eine fehlerhafte Verwendung tippen. Kannst du zur Frage noch ergänzen, was dein Bekannter konkret meint, wenn er einem Mitarbeiter ein Gehalt *stundet*? Meint er vorschießen? Meint er einbehalten?

Comment: Eher würde es Sinn ergeben, dass der Mitarbeiter seinem Arbeitgeber das Gehalt stundet.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Weder *vorschiessen* noch *einbehalten* wären richtige Verwendungen von *stunden von Gehalt*. Der Schuldner (und das ist bei "Gehalt" ja sicher der Arbeitgeber) *kann nicht* stunden (sonst würde das ja wohl jeder machen...). Er kann allerhöchstens in Absprache mit dem Gläubiger eine *Schuld stunden lassen*. Die aktive Rolle hat also immer der Gläubiger.

Comment: @tofro  Aber ja, genau das sage ich doch. *Gehalt stunden* ist einfach Unsinn - jedenfalls solange der *Arbeitgeber* stundet. Darum habe ich einfach nachgefragt, was der Autor denn eigentlich sagen wollte. - Übrigens, so rum geht es dann ja doch: *Der Mitarbeiter stundet dem Arbeitgeber das Gehalt*, sprich: Arbeitgeber hat kein Geld, Mitarbeiter erklärt sich einverstanden, die Gehaltszahlung erst später zu empfangen.

Answer (score 8):

*Stundung* ist ein Begriff aus der Finanzwelt (und es gibt auch ein Verb *stunden* dazu, dass ich aber sehr selten sehe), und bezeichnet das freiwillige Verstreichenlassen eines Zahlungstermins durch den Gläubiger - Sehr einfach ausgedrückt, sagt der Gläubiger zum Schuldner "kannst Du mir auch später zahlen". Wie im Kommentar oben erwähnt, scheint mir dein Zitat allerdings falsch herum verwendet, *stunden einer Schuld* ist eine Aktion, die der *Gläubiger* durchführt, nicht der *Schuldner* - Und bei Gehalt scheint mir eher der Mitarbeiter der Gläubiger zu sein.

Ich glaube nicht, dass das Wort direkt etwas mit der *Stunde* (also der Zeiteinheit) zu tun hat (normalerweise handelt es sich um mehr als ein paar Stunden Zahlungsaufschub), sondern sehe eher etwas wie "Zustand" oder "zugestehen" als Herkunft. Das Wort selbst ist ein uraltes deutsches Wort, von dem ich mir auch aufgrund einiger [Webfunde](https://www.stundung.ch) nicht vorstellen kann, dass es in der Schweiz nicht verwendet wird.

Answer (score 6):

#### [stunden](https://www.dwds.de/wb/stunden)

Dieses ursprünglich in der Bedeutung *Aufschub gewähren, Frist verschieben* gebrauchte Verb trifft man heute fast nur noch in Zusammengang mit Finanzen:

> Zahlungsaufschub gewähren, Zahlungsfrist verlängern.

Dieses Wort gibt oder gab es auch in der Schweiz, laut Einträgen im [Schweizerischen Idiotikon](https://www.idiotikon.ch/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=273&Itemid=195&suchwort=stunden), wenn auch in einer geringfügig weiter gefassten Bedeutung:

> **stunde**: warten, zuwarten, Frist verschieben, vertagen
> **uffstunde**: auf ungewisse Zeit verschieben
> öpperem öppis **bestunde**: jmd. eine Frist setzen für etwas

Zur Nomenbildung findet man: Stundung, Verstundung, Stündigung, Verstündigung, etc.